# restoring files with VShadows does not work

Tags: vss

I've been developing a vss-writer based on [this microsoft sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sample-VSS-Writer-1b3ddbe4).

At the beginning I was using [BETest.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530721%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to test my app

```
> betest.exe /B /S backup.xml /D C:\BackupDestination /X BetestSample.xml
> betest.exe /R /S backup.xml /D C:\BackupDestination /X BetestSample.xml
```

It worked fine. I was able to:

- Backup files from c:\testPath
- Delete them
- Restore them (to a chosen alternate location c:\testPath2.)

But as soon as I tried to backup/restore a 10GB file, the BETest was crashing at the restore operation. Everytime. I looked at other tools:

- VShadow
- VSSAdmin
- WBAdmin

With VShadow, I Typed:

```
> vshadow -p -t=c:\bc.xml c:
```

I could see my Writer printing:

```
enter: DepWriter::Initialize
enter: DepWriter::OnIdentify
enter: DepWriter::OnPrepareBackup
enter: DepWriter::OnPrepareSnapshot
enter: DepWriter::OnFreeze
enter: DepWriter::OnThaw
enter: DepWriter::OnPostSnapshot
enter: DepWriter::OnIdentify
enter: DepWriter::OnBackupComplete
enter: DepWriter::OnBackupShutdown
```

I was able with MKLink to link the shadow copy and to browse it:

```
> mklink /D c:\snapshots \\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy6\
```

I could see the files I wanted to backup.

Then I typed:

```
> vshadow -r=c:\bc.xml
```

output contained (among other things):

```
Sending the PreRestore event ...

(Waiting for the asynchronous operation to finish...)
Set restore status for all components components for restore...
  * Writer 'DFS Replication service writer':
    - Select component \SYSVOL\3E53186A-7D53-4667-A3D1-D278B3564CDC-DF424FA9-3080-403E-B7CE-2A81A03A79FA
  * Writer 'MSDNSampleWriter':
    - Select component \TestFiles

Sending the PostRestore event ...
Restore done.
```

And I got my writer printing printing:

```
enter: DepWriter::OnIdentify
enter: DepWriter::OnPreRestore
enter: DepWriter::OnPostRestore
```

But there was no trace of my files in either c:\testPath or c:\testPath2. They were not restored.

---

---

My VSS Writer is a straight moification of the sample Writer from MSDN and it worked fine for small file with betest.

**Why does VShadow fail to restore my files and tells it is done?** 
I'm using it on windows Server 2008 R2 64Bits

Answer (score 0):

I found a way...

One needs to use the exec={command} switch.

in my case command is a simple:

```
vshadow -p -t=c:\bc.xml -exec="robocopy pathA pathB"
```

I guess normal requester would do something smarter than this though. Most likely it would find alternate locations on its own, have a policy in case of failure... But I can't figure out a better tool than vshadow so far.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384575%28v=vs.85%29.aspx